# Overwrite add/edit form

Tags: 7, theming

What I would like to do is to have a ?.tpl.php file in which I can write my own HTML content. A minimal example would be:

```
<div class="my-class">
      <?php drupal_render($input_label); ?>
      <br />
      <?php drupal_render($input_text); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, path templates are built-in Drupal 7, so just do this:

page--node--add--blog.tpl.php (for blog)
page--node--add--story.tpl.php (for story)
etc.
etc.

Clear cache!

Comment: It seems that this solution compels me to regenerate all the view. It's not allowing me to overwrite how the form is rendered.

Comment: I figured out how to render the fields: `echo drush_render($form['my_field']['und']['#title']);` for label for example.